# Rechange ID with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello:) Im a javascript newbie and I'm trying to change a div ID with a script.
I have a div with the id "change", and onClick I would like to change the ID "changed", and that I could do, but I would like to click again, and it will return to receive the ID "change". Can you help me?

This is how I did:

```
<script> 
$document.ready( function() {
       $("#change").attr('id','changed');
});
});
```

Thanx.

Comment: Blaster's anwser does exactly what you ask but since you stated you are a begginer it might be wise to warn you that it probably is not the best solution for whatever your problem is. Like others suggested, you can change the element class or track changes on other ways than modifying the ID, which should be constant and unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not change the id -- instead use the class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This would also work:

```
$document.ready(function () {
  // This assumes the element always starts with the id `change`
  // If this is a poor assumption, change it to $('#change, #changed')
  $("#change").toggle(function () {
    this.id = 'changed';
  }, function () {
    this.id = 'change';
  });
});
```

Comment: Probably would be better to use `.prop()`, or just `this.id = ...`

Comment: Glad we could help! Please consider accepting one of the answers on this page so others will know what helped you. This is also a reward system for all the nice folks who want to help you out here on SO.